# 2016-02-09 15:00:18,699 ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-7 errors.GrailsExceptionResolver TypeMismatchException occurred when processing request: [POST]

Tags: grails

I am getting below when trying to save data from the frontend form to backend.
Please find the log from the debugger below

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class com.xxx.yyy.domain.vendor.Product. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.xxx.yyy.domain.vendor.Product. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
at com.xxx.yyy.web.controller.DNISCodeController$$EPcFV7Qu.validateElements(DNISCodeController.groovy:198)
at com.xxx.yyy.web.controller.DNISCodeController$_closure10$$EPcFV7Qu.doCall(DNISCodeController.groovy:150)
at com.xxx.yyy.filter.RetainAnchorFilter.doFilter(RetainAnchorFilter.java:57)
at com.xxx.yyy.filter.ExpiryFilter.doFilterInternal(ExpiryFilter.groovy:27)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Could you please help to resolve this soon?

Comment: In your invisible code, you're trying to do something involving the id field of Product. You're passing a string. It should be a Long.

Comment: TIm, from frontend , we are using only name of that field and not using id .Even the product class is extending Vendor class which is having field - Long id

Comment: From the frontend the value you are sending for id field is of type string and not long. Print the params.id in your DNISCodeController code before exception occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import com.xxx.yyy.domain.vendor.Product

Product.get(params.id as Long)
```